# Yii - Error 400 The CSRF token could not be verified

Tags: authentication, yii, csrf, bad-request

I have a very strange problem. I have a login form in Yii which works fine. After moving the website to another server I get

> Error 400 The CSRF token could not be verified

I don't understand why it is working on the development server but not on the new server. here is my code:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
       'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and here is the csrf configuration in my config file:

```
'enableCsrfValidation' => !isset($_POST['dontvalidate']) ? true : false,
```

if you need to see the example. [Here](http://marionette-cola.linkmesrl.com/admin/) is the one which is working, and [here](http://www.marionettecolla.org/admin) is the one with the problem

Comment: Perhaps your [`cookieParams`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#setCookieParams-detail) are not valid in the context of the new deployment?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the first example and found this html in source, This is correct.

```
<input type="hidden" value="df5a0fc9ab86f85cdcdabe6b2ee62e85d3ac0323" 
      name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN" />
```

on the second example page, I haven't found any html code as above. That means **enableCsrfValidation**  is set to **false** in second example.

try debugging  $_POST['dontvalidate']  in this page (or in config/main.php ).

Comment: I don't know why since it was the same code I uploaded to the other server. Anyways, in config/main.php I set the enableCsrfValidation to false, so completely disabled it, and it works now. But it is not the best way to go I guess!